# UISpec4J - AbstractMethodError (UISpecToolkit.createKeyboardFocusManagerPeer)

Tags: java, swing, maven, uispec4j

I am building a simple Swing based Java application and would like to add some simple end-to-end tests. I have come across the [UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org) library and imported it into my Maven project like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.uispec4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>uispec4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I also have the following Main class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There does not seem to be a lot of materials about UISpec4J available on the Internet but according to a few tutorials that I managed to find the following code should work:

```
public class CanFillInABasicFormTest extends UISpecTestCase
{
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        setAdapter(new MainClassAdapter(Main.class, new String[0]));
    }

    @Test
    public void test() 
    {
        Window mainWindow = getMainWindow();
    }
}
```

But instead it fails with the following exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.UISpecToolkit.createKeyboardFocusManagerPeer(Ljava/awt/KeyboardFocusManager;)Ljava/awt/peer/KeyboardFocusManagerPeer;
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.initPeer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.put(Unknown Source)
    at org.uispec4j.interception.ui.UISpecLF.init(UISpecLF.java:11)
    at org.uispec4j.UISpec4J.init(UISpec4J.java:32)
    at org.uispec4j.UISpecTestCase.<clinit>(UISpecTestCase.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:61)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:294)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:150)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:129)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:14)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, the UISpec4J library is the first one that Google recommended to me but I am opened for suggestions to other functional testing libraries as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching to jdk1.6 update 0 worked for me. I was using jdk1.7 and I got the same error.

Moreover, I think that annotations are not necessary, because you are using junit3 (extending UISpecTestCase, that extends TestCase)

```
public class CanFillInABasicFormTest extends UISpecTestCase {
    public void setUp() {
        setAdapter(new MainClassAdapter(Main.class, new String[0]));
    }

    public void test() {
        Window mainWindow = getMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you just run via jdk1.6 or changed JAVA_HOME too? Switching to jdk1.6 gave me
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: uispec4j/HealthIndicatorsProModeTest : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in class *org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.UISpecToolkit* which was created before java 1.7. Class *UISpecToolkit* implements abstract class *org.uispec4j.interception.toolkit.ToolkitDelegate*. *ToolkitDelegate* extends another abstract class *SunToolkit*. Class *SunToolkit* is root of problems. In Java 1.7 there is a new abstract method:

> KeyboardFocusManagerPeer sun.awt.SunToolkit.getKeyboardFocusManagerPeer()

This method is not implemented in class UISpecToolkit. In *SunToolkit* in Java 1.7 is also new method:

> protected abstract boolean syncNativeQueue(final long timeout);

It's not possible to easily add new implementation of this *SunToolkit* to uispec4j. So without new library release or some non trivial effort it's not possible to use uispec4j library at java 1.7.